# Improving my github workflow

Tags: git, version-control, github

I work with various developers on various apps.
I need to know how my workflow can be improved.

- Within the repository the 'master' is always an exact copy of the live code.
- For each set of features we create a branch.
- We name the branch by the version number v1, v1-0-1, v1-0-2, v1.1, etc
- We are able to test locally and on a dev server using the subdomain as the branch name.
  `i.e. http://version.mydomain.com` - pulled with a post-commit
- When we are ready I merge the version into the master - test again, then launch

Most importantly...

*How could this workflow generally be improved?*

And secondarily...

*I often have to deal with conflicts when merging into master - can this be avoided?*

*In the last stage I wonder if I should be using a 'rebase' rather than a 'merge'?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)? We have just switched over to it from a system similar to your description and it's made a world of difference. There's also a [set of command line tools](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) to support it.

Answer (score 2):

> I often have to deal with conflicts when merging into master - can
>   this be avoided?

This suggests that you're not committing frequently enough.  Commit early and often and your merging issues will be smaller and more manageable.  The longer you wait, and the more people you have working on a project, the higher the likelihood of conflicts.

Comment: I'd prefer an upvote and acceptance to your thanks.  Good for me, good for you.

Comment: +1 for sure. I'm waiting to see if I get an answer to my main question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a design pattern but a workflow. There is [this workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) that has gotten very popular. It's explained in detail in the article. There is even a [git-flow extension](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) for git.